# Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering

Tags: android

I have a Live Wallpaper app that handle images.

I'm getting some crashes report in the Play Store (but not in fabric.io) with this stack trace:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hero2ltexx/hero2lte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G935FXXU1APDN:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 15250, tid: 15331, name: RenderThread  >>> com.xxxx.xxxxx <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering'
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000003be3  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000000
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   fefeff7e6032ce0b  x10  7f7f7f7f7f7fff7f  x11  0101010101010101
    x12  0000000000000010  x13  0000007f6f425bdc  x14  0000000000000001  x15  000000000000000f
    x16  0000007f9422f568  x17  0000007f941c23b8  x18  0000007f945cf720  x19  0000007f6f426500
    x20  0000007f6f426440  x21  0000000000000019  x22  0000000000000006  x23  0000007f6132f6c0
    x24  0000007f6132e800  x25  0000007f614fd7b0  x26  0000000000000002  x27  0000007f70602bb0
    x28  0000007f6eb58c10  x29  0000007f6f425b80  x30  0000007f941bfb54
    sp   0000007f6f425b80  pc   0000007f941c23c0  pstate 0000000020000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000000693c0  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
    #01 pc 0000000000066b50  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
    #02 pc 0000000000023990  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
    #03 pc 000000000001e2c0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
    #04 pc 000000000000cf04  /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+236)
    #05 pc 000000000002be6c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
    #06 pc 00000000000284f4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
    #07 pc 000000000002aa68  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
    #08 pc 000000000002ef50  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+124)
    #09 pc 000000000001699c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208)
    #10 pc 0000000000095110  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96)
    #11 pc 00000000000161ec  /system/lib64/libutils.so
    #12 pc 0000000000065fa0  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
    #13 pc 000000000001ee6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

I cannot find many informations on internet... it seems a Samsung issue only.

Comment: I also have same problem. if you find the solution, Please don't forget to share

Comment: Looks like have patches.
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/197520/
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/186482/ Please check it.

Comment: I've seen this on a ZTE w 6.0.1. identical call stack (not a livewallpaper - just a regular app).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue from a service, it crash when the service get destroyed, onDestroy remove some view on the WindowManager.

The solution I found working is to remove the view using **removeViewImmediate** instead of **removeView**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
  windowManager.removeView(view);
}
```

replaced by

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
  windowManager.removeViewImmediate(view);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html#removeViewImmediate(android.view.View)

Not sure why yet this solve it, the doc is light...

It only happened on Samsung device that use Android 6.0.1 (mainly S6 and S7).

Comment: It's happening to me too with an Samsung S6 with android 6.0.1

Comment: Hi, I'm getting similar problem: when I open the BottomSheetDialog, everything is working fine. But within 1s after the BottomSheetDialog is shown, app crash with the that error. Any suggestions? Thanks.